# Disallow no index for robots.txt on a tags or links for a server in an iFrame on another server?

Tags: html, server, robots.txt

I have dynamic URLs like `/what?flagtopic=123123`.

Can I add a `noindex` attribute to a tag? The page is in an iFrame on another domain, so this domain's robots.txt won't work for the iFrame right?

Do I use `Disallow: /what\?flagtopic\=*`?

Answer (score 2):

if you use a layout for your dynamic URL pages you can use `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">` there([more info](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en)).

and if you show a link in your page which you don't need to be crawled rather than edit robots.txt you can use `rel="nofollow"` with the link([more info](https://ahrefs.com/blog/nofollow-links/)).

it's better to use [Search Console](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) to find out more about this and other potential crawling errors on your site.[found this in google](https://www.boostability.com/the-affect-of-iframes-on-seo/) Please take a look for how iframes affect SEO.

To block access to all URLs that include question marks (?). For example, the sample code blocks URLs that begin with your domain name, followed by any string, followed by a question mark, and ending with any string:

```
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*?
```

[check Google’s robots.txt documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en)

[another article I found on iframe related SEO](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/iframe-seo-and-accessibility/)